# Android: Tabs within the Toolbar

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and I was looking for a tutorial which would show me how to have sliding tabs with icons in the toolbar with a navigation drawer.

I just can't find any tutorial. All tutorials give you the sliding tabs below the toolbar.

Does anyone know any good tutorials ?

Thanks

Comment: You can just move the TabLayout inside Toolbar for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a pretty good looking tutorial,  you'll find some more through google.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

You'll need to get your head around the coordinator view if you want any of the nice scrolling behaviour